# Calculation with jquery and grouping of sub-totals

Tags: jquery, html, math

I'm working on a web application and want to create something like an invoice calculation, but with sub-groups, so at the end I need the result of the group-totals and the sub-totals.

This is what I got so far: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yaMRQ/9)

```
$(function() {
    $("#items").keyup(function(event) {
        var total = 0;
        $("#items .targetfields").each(function() {
            var qty = parseInt($(this).find(".quantity").val());
            var rate = parseInt($(this).find(".rate").val());
            var subtotal = qty * rate;
            $(this).find(".subtotal").val(subtotal);
            if (!isNaN(subtotal)) total += subtotal;
        });
        $("#total").html(total);
    });
})
```

Ultimately, I'm working towards something like this:

[image]

I have found a lot of examples about invoice calculation but not with groups or sub-totals.

I hoped someone could help me out with a little example.

Comment: so what is the problem? the fiddle is working...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if this is what you had in mind: http://jsfiddle.net/yaMRQ/23/

```
<table class="items">
    <tr class="targetfields"> 
        <td><input type="text" name="quantity" class="quantity" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="rate" class="rate" size="5" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="sub_total" class="subtotal" /></td> 
    </tr> 
    <tr class="targetfields"> 
        <td><input type="text" name="quantity" class="quantity" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="rate" class="rate" size="5" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="sub_total" class="subtotal" /></td> 
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Group:</td>
        <td colspan="2" align="right" class="g_total"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<table class="items">
    <tr class="targetfields"> 
        <td><input type="text" name="quantity" class="quantity" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="rate" class="rate" size="5" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="sub_total" class="subtotal" /></td> 
    </tr> 
    <tr class="targetfields"> 
        <td><input type="text" name="quantity" class="quantity" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="rate" class="rate" size="5" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="sub_total" class="subtotal" /></td> 
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Group:</td>
        <td colspan="2" align="right" class="g_total"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<br/>---<br/>Total: <span id="total"></span>
```

​

```
$(function() {
    $(".items").keyup(function(event) {
     var total = 0;
     $(".items").each(function(){
         var gtotal = 0;
         $(this).find(".targetfields").each(function() {
             var qty = parseInt($(this).find(".quantity").val());
             var rate = parseInt($(this).find(".rate").val());
             var subtotal = qty * rate;
             $(this).find(".subtotal").val(subtotal);
             if(!isNaN(subtotal))
                 gtotal+=subtotal;
         });
         $(this).find(".g_total").html("EUR "+gtotal); 
         total+=gtotal
     });
     $("#total").html("EUR "+total);
    });
})​
```

Comment: wow thats exactly what im searching for, now i have to add the syntax for adding the input and group tables dynamically. thanks alot for the fast help :) i post my result then here..

Comment: Glad it helped :) Feel free to mark the question as answered.

Comment: the script runs fine if the tables are static and already coded, if i add an table per append(), the calculator doestn work on the new fields, only if i add some values and then change a value in an static table. looks like the new html elements wouldn't found :( can you point me out ? What i got so far : http://jsfiddle.net/yaMRQ/29/

Comment: solved by myself, i use now $(".items").live("keyup",function(){ instead of $(".items").keyup(function(event) { and it works :)

Comment: well done! indeed, `live` binds events to elements yet to be added to the DOM.